# Vuejs : Include local javascript file with <script> tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, venn

I would like to include in a vuejs component this jquery plugin : http://jvenn.toulouse.inra.fr/app/js/jvenn.min.js.

to do so, I added these lines

```
mounted () {
  const jvenn = document.createElement('script')
  jvenn.setAttribute(
    'src',
    'http://jvenn.toulouse.inra.fr/app/js/jvenn.min.js'
  )
  jvenn.async = true
  document.head.appendChild(jvenn)
}
```

it works fine, but I'd like to have a local copy of this script in case this file will no longer be online. I tryed to add it in my assets directory, and to change http://jvenn.toulouse.inra.fr/app/js/jvenn.min.js by /static/js/jvenn.min.js without success.

Any idea ?

Comment: you don't need first `/`

Comment: "without success" - Have you done any debugging? Are you using the browser console and network pane?

Comment: `static` is not a prefixed directory. It is mapped directly into the root at both run and compile time. therefore, `/js/jvenn.min.js` will work.

Comment: @FlYiNGPoTAToChiP and @Ohgodwhy it returns the error  `$(...).jvenn is not a function`

Comment: Why not keep it global in your index.html included?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a Vue CLI scaffolded project, put the third party script in the [`public` folder](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder) to make it a static asset:

```
public
└─js
|  └─jvenn.min.js
└─index.html
```

Then edit `public/index.html` to import the script:

```html
<body>
  <script src="<%= BASE_URL %>js/jvenn.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

*The `<%= BASE_URL %>` prefix in `src` is important if the project's base URL is configured.*

Answer (score 0):

if

```
js
└─jvenn.min.js
index.html
```

then it will be just `js/jvenn.min.js`

Comment: I should have clearer mentioned, I'm using vuejs, I added the info in the title